# Algorithm - Dynamic tree view with no empty folders (collapsed node paths)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, treeview

I'm trying to create a tree view from file paths, which can be added and removed dinamically, for instance:

```
A/B/C/D/file1.txt
A/B/D/E/file2.txt
A/B/D/G/file3.txt
A/B/D/G/file4.txt
```

I already created a tree like the following:

```
A
|---B
    |---C
    |   |---D
    |       file1.txt
    |---D
        |---E
        |   file2.txt
        |---G
            file3.txt
            file4.txt
```

My tree however, has a requirement that paths with no child items (files) should be collapsed in one node. For the paths above it would yield:

```
A/B
  |---C/D
       file1.txt   
  |---D
      |---E
      |    file2.txt
      |---G
           file3.txt
```

Any suggestions on how would I go about doing that? I assume I'd have to use some kind of recursion as I go adding items and breaking the paths as we find that a certain path has more children (and then doing the same recursively?). Any known algorithms?

I also need to support removals. So If I removed "A/B/D/G/file3.txt" and "A/B/D/G/file4.txt", it would result in D being an empty folder, so I'd move E up and I'd be left with:

```
A/B
  |---C/D
       file1.txt   
  |---D/E
       file2.txt
```

So you see that tree nodes can be collapsed/expanded depending on the paths we dynamically add/remove.

Any ideas? I'm trying to implement this in JS..

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone? I'm sort of stuck..

Comment: Hi, lets try to work something out together.  Are there any performance constraints on this problem, given whatever input size you want?

Comment: Not particularly. I think the input size would be in the several tens of thousands to lower hundreds of thousands... do you have anything in mind?

Comment: This is sort of how crit bit trees work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that you should recalculate your tree on every insertion/deletion.

So the problem now is to build this tree representation for your tree.

The idea is that you should label your nodes for files and directories. Then you should mark every folder node with `True` if there are one and more file children or strictly more than one folder nodes (the meaning of this mark is that you should skip endline and tabulation and add slash). You can do it for example using DFS algorithm  (for every node check all children and mark this node).

Then you should output or draw your tree, you can do it using preorder traversal while maintaining current depth.

If current node hasn't `mark` then output your folder name and add endline then output tab symbols multiplied by depth + 1 of you current node. Then you should call your function for children and pass there depth + 1.

If the current node has `mark` than you should output all the same except you skip `endline` and tabulation in the end but instead you should add '/'. Also you should pass only depth(without plus one) for recursive calls for the correct tabulation of children.